# Contact form 7 onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

i am complete JS newbie, so if somebody can help with this issue, that would be great.

I have multiple contact forms on my site, and i would need to include custom JS event tracking code on each of submit buttons.

If it was a simple field, i would just add this code to it:

```
onClick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Form', eventAction: 'Call', eventLabel: 'Send', eventValue: 100});"
```

but i dont know how to do so with [submit "Send"] button. There are few tutorials for using on_sent_ok function in CF7, but i am completely lost...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

How about avoiding all of this stuff and just replace

`[submit "SEND MESSAGE"]`

with

`<input type="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'form', 'submit', 'success');" />`

Comment: This is a good idea, but the onclick event does not work.. And if it does (for others reasons) the CF7 does not send - submit the form, in order to send mail

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your theme `functions.php` file (create it if it doesn't exist).

```
/**
 * Add the code that will run when on_sent_ok is triggered;
 */
function my_plugin_wpcf7_properties( $properties, $instance /* unused */ ){
    $properties[ 'additional_settings' ] .= "\n" . "ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Form', eventAction: 'Call', eventLabel: 'Send', eventValue: 100});";
    return $properties;
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_contact_form_properties', 'my_plugin_wpcf7_properties' , 10, 2 );
```

If you want different JS code depending on form ID, you can use the 2nd parameter:

```
/**
 * Add the code that will run when on_sent_ok is triggered;
 */
function my_plugin_wpcf7_properties( $properties, $instance ){
    if ( 1 == $instance->id ) {
        $properties[ 'additional_settings' ] .= "\n" . "console.log('Form ID:1');";
    } else if ( 2 == $instance->id ) {
        $properties[ 'additional_settings' ] .= "\n" . "console.log('Form ID:2');";
    } else if ( 3 == $instance->id ) {
        $properties[ 'additional_settings' ] .= "\n" . "console.log('Form ID:3');";
    }
    return $properties;
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_contact_form_properties', 'my_plugin_wpcf7_properties' , 10, 2 );
```

Extracted from a [blog post](http://kadimi.com/wpcf7-javascript-programmatically/)  I wrote

Comment: but what if i have multiple forms and multiple onClick codes that i would like to use? and thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you mean that the `eventValue` is different for forms?

Comment: everything is different (event category, eventaction, eventlabel and eventvalue)... there are 3 different forms and each of them needs to have separate onclick atrributes...

Comment: Makes sense... Updated

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, but it's not the most clean one as you have to modify plugin code.

In the submit.php file I've created the following if statement

```
global $post;
    if($post->ID == 19 || $post->ID == 135) {
       return $html; 
    }
    else {
       return $secondhtml; 
    }
```

As i have several forms I have different onclick events for them so depending on post ID I return different variable containing the input code